# Why I can not using $this with get_object_vars

Tags: php

```
<?php 
     require_once 'database.php';
class User {
public $id;
public $username;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;
public $password;
public static function find_by_id($id){
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1");
    return !(empty($result_array))? array_shift($result_array): false;
}
public static function find_by_sql($sql){
    global $database;
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    $object = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetct_array($result)){
     $object[] = self::instantiate($row);  
    }
    return $object;
}
public static function instantiate($record)
        {
    $object = new self;
    foreach($record as $attribute => $value)
        {
        if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
private static function has_attribute($attribute){       
    $object_var = get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_var);


}
}
?>
```

I got error when I try to call function has_attribute. **Notice: Undefined variable: this**

Why I cannot use this in `get_object_vars` in private function `has_attribute($attribute)`.
Can anyone help me with that? 
Thank you.

Comment: Your `has_attribute()` method is static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this` is not defined in static methods (they belong to the class in general, not to specific object) - but *all* the methods in your class are defined as `static`.

You might want to change the `has_attribute` method so it'll take the instance of `User` as a param, but I don't think that's good design. In fact, I don't understand why do you need this method at all: for all the cases when non-existing property of an object is accessed, so-called [magic method __get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) is called automatically:

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties
>   or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the
>   current scope. [...] `__get()` is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

If you defined `has_attribute` to prevent accessing non-existing properties (log these attempts, for example), move the code into `__get`.

Comment: How to fix the that problems if I cannot using this here?

Comment: I just want to access the current instance of the class.

Comment: There's no `current instance of the class` within static method - you call it from a class, not from an object context. Why have you made this function `static`? Why do you need this method, when you can just `isset($userObject->someproperty)`?

Answer (score 2):

That is because **`$this`** keyword is not accesible on a static context.

[`Source`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)